# Android SwitchPreference using Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout

I've an activity to represent a preference screen using one FragmentPreference.

**Activity layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/frag"
    android:name="com.test.preference.Frag"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**Preference xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<PreferenceCategory android:title="General">
    <SwitchPreference android:title="Enable module" android:key="asd" android:summaryOff="Turn on module" android:summaryOn="Turn off module"/>
    <SwitchPreference android:title="Post in application" android:key="qwe" android:summary="Show posts in application"/>
    <SwitchPreference android:title="Post in widget" android:key="zxc" android:summary="Show posts in widget"/>
</PreferenceCategory>
```

**Activity class:**

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
}
```

and finally **Fragment class:**

```
public class Frag extends PreferenceFragment{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.test);
}
}
```

Activity starts normally but when I click on a first SwitchPreference, its status remains equal and the other two SwitchPreference change their status!

If I use deprecated method (PreferenceActivity without fragment) it works.

Someone can help me?

Giulio

Comment: I'm having the same problem in a fragment. Did you ever get this working?

Comment: For those that might find this... I found the problem. I was using heme.Holo.Light.Dialog for the settings activity. I changed it to android:Theme.Holo.NoActionBar. Works fine now.